# \n\r Not removed by PHP functions

Tags: php

On my home page, I display some info about the hikes (it is a hiking site) and embarassinlgy, 
the \r\n characters still show up.

I do these functons

```
$hike_description = htmlspecialchars ($hike_description);
$hike_description = nl2br($hike_description);
```

And still those characters do not go away.  You can take a look yourself at http://www.comehike.com

Would you know what is the proper way to get rid of the \r\n characters?  You can see it happening in the "Upcoming Hikes" section...on the 3rd hike.

Thanks!

Comment: It's odd that you actually see `\n\r` rather than what they represent.  Sounds to me like the problem is with your source text.  Can you provide a literal example of what you are trying to properly convert to HTML?

Comment: Have you looked at [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)?

Comment: it looks like it's only doing it on that page. If I click on the link and view the full hike, it displays the br's properly instead of the \r\n's. Look at what is working on the full hike page.

Comment: You shouldn't be able to see the \r\n's.. try str_replace(array("\r","\n"),'<br />',$hike_description)

Comment: @Brad the source text in the database has the \r\n also

Comment: @Genadinik: Understood, however you're looking for "\n" in your string, when what's really in there is "\\n" (if both were typed out in a source file). If you `stripslashes` first, then remove you'll be then removing the actual control characters, not just "a slash then an N".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, the following will work:

```
$hike_description = str_replace ( "\\r\\n","<br />", $hike_description);
```

The text `\r\n` is literal, rather than control characters.

Answer (score 2):

Try manually replacing the sequence

```
str_replace( "\r\n", "<br />", $hike_description );
```

Answer (score 1):

The `\n\r` in your page are not escape sequences... They are actually a `\` character followed by a `n` character followed by a `\` character followed by a `r` character.

In your database, you should store that as the actual characters, not the escape sequences. Then, calling `nl2br()` will work as expected.

Yes, you can do a `str_replace()`, however, you should instead fix the encoding of your data in your database. It will save you trouble in the future.

Comment: when I insert into the db, I just do the mysql_real_escape_string() - is that not the right way to go?

Comment: @Genadinik: Yes it is... However, it might be your source data that is the problem....